# Remove loading template for non-logged in users in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im using pub/sub on my application, but when no user is logged in, the subscription defers to the `waitOn` method and loads my `loadingTemplate`

```
 loadingTemplate: 'loading',
      waitOn: function(){
          return Meteor.subscribe('lists');
     }
```

I want the following spacebars to kick in, but the `waitOn` method is blocking it

```
   {{#unless currentUser}}
        <div class="alert alert-error">
        log in to access your kaleo
        </div>
        <h2 class='login-welcome'>sign in above to access your kaleo</h2>
    {{/unless}}
```

Comment: Is the issue that the loading template renders and then won't go away, or that it renders at all?

Comment: that it renders at all, but more annoyingly that it stays there.  there is no user logged in, so the userId() parameter of the pub/sub is never met.  There is nothing to `waitOn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a publish function which will fail when the user isn't logged in, it's usually best to `return this.ready()`. For example:

```
Meteor.publish('lists', function() {
  if (!this.userId)
    return this.ready();

  return Lists.find({owner: this.userId});
});
```

That should solve your immediate problem that the loading template is stuck on. Technically, however, the `waitOn` will still run and the delay may be more pronounced in a production environment. You could try something like this:

```
waitOn: function(){
  if (Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.userId())
    return Meteor.subscribe('lists');
}
```

That should avoid the subscription when the user is not logged in, but I haven't tested it myself.